# Shell Printf: Invalid Number error

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have a file named exfile(4 numbers per line):

```
200807 0 96 200807
```

I want to read this file and use all the 4 numbers.

My Shell script is:

```
while read line
do
    echo ${line}
    set ${line}
    echo "${1} ${2} ${3} ${4}"
    declare -i start
    declare -i end
    start=`expr ${2} / 1`
    end=`expr ${3} / 1`
    for i in {${start}..${end}}
    do
        picnum=`printf "%03d" $i`
        echo ${picnum}
    done
done < exfile
```

The error is `printf: {0..96}: invalid number`

if you delete the lines:

```
declare -i start
declare -i end
start=`expr ${2} / 1`
end=`expr ${3} / 1`
```

The error is the same. I add these lines to turn strings into integers.

Any idea why? Thanks a lot.

=============================================

Updated:The following code works:

```
while read line
do
    echo ${line}
    set ${line}
    echo "${1} ${2} ${3} ${4}"
    for i in $(seq ${2} ${3})
    do
        picnum=`printf "%03d" $i`
        echo ${picnum}
    done
done < exfile
```

Comment: You don't need to "convert" a number from a string. The shell is not strongly typed. Arguments to commands are strings anyway, and if the command needs to interpret an argument as a number, it will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brace expansion happens before parameter expansion. `"{${start}..${end}}"` is not a valid brace expansion expression and so is left unexpanded. Use `seq` instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error. But I am not familiar with seq. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Problems solved! Thanks 4 ur help. The code is `for i in $(seq ${2} ${3})`

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop should be like this:

```
for((i=$2;i<=$3;i++))
```